# My URL Rewrites/Reverse Proxy in IIS is not working as desired. Can anyone please double check my setup?

Tags: windows, iis, web-server

I have a base website (www.example.com) that is working fine. I would like to redirect a subdomain (jellyfin.example.com) to an alternate port on the same IP address that the main domain is residing.

It is being hosted on my computer, so I am trying to redirect jellyfin.example.com to 127.0.0.1:8920.

Here is my URL Rewrite rule: https://a.uguu.se/kcIcwiFiDdVE.png

Here are my Server Proxy Settings: https://a.uguu.se/08lpqxnghHfG.png

At the bottom of the Server Proxy Settings is a Proxy Type section. I have a feeling that the 'Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests' option needs to be selected, however that requires entering a path  in the 'Reverse proxy' field below it. I am unsure what to place there.

Thanks to anyone who can offer advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it doesn't appear that DNS - at least not *public* DNS - has been set up for the subdomain jellyfin.duncanbennie.com. Second, you need to change the pattern to just `(.*)`. Add a Condition, choose `{HTTP_HOST}`, leave `Matches the pattern` selected, and the pattern will be `^jellyfin\.example\.com$`. Finally, check `Append query string` in case you plan to use them in the future. The rest of your rule settings are fine. ARR settings look like they are the default, which is also fine.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Please mark it as answer too!